# Why not use the $L^2$ norm as the difference between two probability distributions (as opposed to KL-Divergence and others)

Tags: distributions, distance, kullback-leibler, distance-functions

So I was wondering why not just use:

$$dist(p,q)=\bigg(\int_{x \in X} |p(x)-q(x)|^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}$$ instead of the commonly used KL-Divergence, which isn't even a distance measure and therefore not symmetric.

What is it lacking compared to those other solutions? One option I thought of is that it doesn't take into account the 'weight' (frequency) of the different $x$ in the probability distribution of interest, but surely one could adapt this to account for that. What, then, are the main reasons for not wanting to use this or a weighted adaptation of this?

Comment: This question lacks necessary context: what is the proposed application of this norm?  It's also confusing, because the formula has nothing to do with the "sample" you refer to later.  Finally, the notation is strange and confusing too: is this an integral (where you have omitted the measure) or a sum (that you have written with an integral sign)?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I've fixed the question. As for the purpose - well, that's part of the question -- KL-Divergence is widely used. Perhaps someone has an example of its use where $L^2$ would not capture the correct relationship.

Comment: It sounds like you're flipping the roles of question and answer.  We're not set up here on CV to examine potential answers and provide lists of questions to which they might apply.